# unique_ptr and forward declaration: the proper way to code a factory function

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, forward-declaration

Learned smart ptrs recently, I'm trying to write a factory function that returns unique_ptrs. Having read several articles about putting the time of creation along with explicitly defined ctor and dtor in the same cpp file, I thought I could do this:

```
// factory.hpp

struct Foo;

std::unique_ptr<Foo> create();
```

```
// foo.cpp

struct Foo {
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    Foo(const Foo &);
    Foo(Foo &&);
};

std::unique_ptr<Foo> create() {
    return make_unique<Foo>();
}
```

```
#include "factory.hpp"


int main() {
    auto r = create();
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting THE incomplete type error. Then after several hours of web searching and experiments,
I realize that I can't even do this:

Here's the classic unique_ptr Pimpl idiom.

```
// A.hpp

struct B;

struct A {
    A();
    ~A();
    unique_ptr<B> b;
};
```

```
// A.cpp

struct B {};

A::A() = default;

A::~A() = default;
```

```
#include "A.hpp"


int main() {
    A a;   // this is fine since we are doing the Pimpl correctly.

    // Now, I can't do this.
    auto b = std::move(a.b);   // <--- Can't do this.

    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of discussion, please ignore the fact that the `std::move` line makes no frigging sense.
I got the same incomplete type error.

The above two cases are essentially the same. And after some searching, I guess I understand the reason behind the error,
but I want some pointers (pun intended) and confirmation from you guys.

1. It's UB to delete an incomplete type. That's why it's forbidden to create unique_ptrs w/ incomplete types using default deleters.
2. If I use custom deleters, I should be able to do this.
3. I'm guessing since I'm using default deleters in my case, I can't be done for some reason I'm not quite sure about.

Explicitly define create and destroy functions should do the trick. But to me, it's ugly. For one, default deleters will do in my case.
For another, it seems to me I can't use lambda for the destroyer, as the type of lambda is known only to the compiler,
and I can't do my factory function declaration with `decltype`.

So my questions are:

1. What's the reason behind this failure?
2. What's the proper way to write factory functions that returns unique_ptrs?

Please correct me if anything I've said is wrong. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You declared `create` in factory.hpp and then defined `create` (as a non-inline function) in foo.hpp. What's going on there?

Comment: @Kerndog73 Sorry, it's a typo. Edited. Supposed to be a cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the compiler instantiates the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`, the compiler must find `Foo::~Foo()` and call it. This means that `Foo` must be a complete type at the point where `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` is destroyed.

This code is fine:

```
struct Foo;

std::unique_ptr<Foo> create();
```

...as long as you don't need to call the destructor of `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`! For a factory function that returns an `std::unique_ptr` to a class, that class needs to be a complete type. This is how you would declare the factory:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

std::unique_ptr<Foo> create();
```

You seem to be implementing pimpl with an `std::unique_ptr` correctly. You must define `A::~A()` at the point where `B` is complete (which is in the cpp file). You must define `A::A()` in the same place because `B` must be complete if you want to allocate memory and call its constructor.

So this is fine:

```
// a.hpp

struct A {
  A();
  ~A();

private:
  struct B;
  std::unique_ptr<B> b;
};

// a.cpp

struct A::B {
  // ...  
};

A::A()
  : b{std::make_unique<B>()} {}

A::~A() = default;
```

Now let's consider this (we'll pretend that I didn't make `b` private):

```
int main() {
  A a;
  auto b = std::move(a.b);
}
```

What exactly is going on here?

1. We are move constructing a `std::unique_ptr<B>` to initialize `b`.
2. `b` is a local variable which means that its destructor will be called at the end of the scope.
3. `B` must be a complete type when the destructor for `std::unique_ptr<B>` is instantiated.
4. `B` is an incomplete type so we cannot destroy `b`.

Ok, so you cannot pass around an `std::unique_ptr<B>` if `B` is an incomplete type. This restriction makes sense. pimpl means "pointer to implementation". It doesn't make sense for external code to access the implementation of `A` so `A::b` should be private. If you must access `A::b` then this is not pimpl, this is something else.

If you really must access `A::b` while keeping the definition of `B` hidden then there are a few workarounds.

`std::shared_ptr<B>`. This deletes the object polymorphically so that `B` doesn't need to be a complete type when the destructor of `std::shared_ptr<B>` is instantiated. It's not quite as fast as `std::unique_ptr<B>` and I personally prefer to avoid `std::shared_ptr` unless absolutely necessary.

`std::unique_ptr<B, void(*)(B *)>`. Similar to the way that `std::shared_ptr<B>` deletes the object. A function pointer is passed on construction that is responsible for deleting. This has the overhead of carrying around a function pointer unnecessarily.

`std::unique_ptr<B, DeleteB>`. The fastest possible solution. However, it's probably a little bit annoying if you have more than a handful of pimpl (but not really pimpl) classes because you can't define a template. This is how you would do it:

```
// a.hpp

struct DeleteB {
  void operator()(B *) const noexcept;
};

// a.cpp

void DeleteB::operator()(B *b) const noexcept {
  delete b;
}
```

Defining a custom deleter is probably the best option but if I were you, I'd find a way to avoid needing to access implementation details from outside the class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree to your opinion on avoiding `shared_ptr` and unnecessary function pointer. So to sum up, if I don't want to include the class prototype, I have to provide a custom deleter. And the best way is to use a functor like your `DeleteB`. One more follow up question, the functor case does not incur any extra space, correct?

Comment: @TerryTsao Yep. That's it.

Comment: Another follow up question, for the functor case, it doesn't incur any extra space or time compared to default delete ones, am I thinking correctly?

Comment: @TerryTsao That's right. `DeleteB` requires no extra space or time compared to `std::default_delete<B>`. In fact, `std::default_delete` is defined very similarly.